# Why is gravitational potential energy shared between two particles?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

By integrating the gravitational force $F_g=GMm/r^2$, you get the potential energy function $U(r)=-GMm/r$. Halliday and Resnick’s *Fundamentals of Physics* states,

> The potential energy given by [$U(r)=-GMm/r$] is a property of the system of two particles rather than of either particle alone. There is no way to divide this energy and say that so much belongs to one particle and so much to the other.

I do not understand why this energy belongs to the system. If each particle in the system experiences a force $F_g=GMm/r^2$, then shouldn’t *each* particle have the energy $U(r)=-GMm/r$? Why is this quantity divided among the particles in the system?

Comment: No, that's wrong. Just think about the simpler case $U = mgh$. If you say both the object, and the Earth, have $U = mgh$, then the total potential energy is $2mgh$, and energy is not conserved when you move the object.

Comment: The potential energy is due to the interaction. If one object is absent, then there is no force; no potential energy. This is why the 'potential' which describes the conservative gravitational force is something that is there in the 'system'